# Ideas for building a foldable rake

Tags: epoxy

I play beach volleyball and on certain parts of the beach we have either a lot of stones/sticks or waste. And sometimes we hurt ourselves because of it.
Therefore I want to make a foldable rake, as I don't want to carry around a 2m broomstick all the time. It needs to fit into a large backpack.

I found these broomsticks that are foldable and come with a screw-on connector:
[image: foldable broomstick]

And I found such a detachable rake:

[image: wolf-craft detachable rake]

I specifically chose these two as my idea is to remove that screw-top connector of the broom and insert the rake inside it and use a screw and wing nut to fixate the rake head.
But I want to enforce its stability from the inside with epoxy. But how can I "mold" the inside to the rake head without it sticking inside, so I can pull it out again?

Any ideas? Or maybe you have a different approach to make my foldable rake?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a good fit for [diy.se]. However, I would look for a screw on end to put at the end of the "broom stick" part that can then be bolted onto the tang of the rake part. Apply epoxy if the bolt isn't sufficient, but otherwise leave it out of the mix.

Comment: That's a good idea. Maybe just by a cheap brush or something and use the "screw-onto part" and fixate it to the rake.

Comment: Cover the rake shaft with Saran Wrap a thin coating of that plastic will keep the epoxy from bonding if you plan on filling all the way to the hole in the rake shaft fill that so there is no possibility of a divot there. I have tried a heavy grease film and one epoxy did not like the grease, another worked but the fit was so tight I ended up sanding the inner shaft. Different project but same idea I had the best luck with the Saran plastic wrap. Note don’t use styrofoam to try and plug the shaft when filling with epoxy unless you test it first the epoxy dissolved the styrofoam.

Comment: I have had success using @EdBeal 's approach with other epoxy-molding tasks.

Comment: As a possible alternative, consider the fold-lock mechanism on lightweight table legs (such as used by caterers for large parties).  I don't know if you can get a similar locking hinge that goes 180 degrees to fold up, but it's a thought.

Comment: One more wacky idea:  buy the matching handle for the rake, cut it down to  a foot or so in length,    and   either sleeve it or otherwise bolt it to one of the broomstick pieces.

Comment: I like the idea of the foldable rake.  But what if they play without you one day?  If you buy a $10 rake and tie it to one of the stakes of the volleyball net, everyone will know why it is there and people who like to play will be happy to have the rake.  They will put it back when they are done.   When you show up and see them using your old rake, you can hum "Imagine".

Comment: Great tip with the Saran wrap!

Re putting the rake there for others, @Willk:
We have a portable net, like all other players, there is dozens of nets every weekend. So, that's unfortunately not an option, although I like the altruistic thought. :)

Comment: Don't *think* of it as a 2m broomstick! Stride proudly across the beach wielding your **Sand-Wizard's Staff** (robes and pointy hat optional, but highly recommended.) Now, if you could get it to fly, broomstick might be just fine...

Answer (score 1):

I look at those parts, and I think that your broomstick (which might work fine for a broomstick) will probably snap in fairly short order when used with a rake.

A rake handle has much more significant bending forces on it than a broom handle does, in normal use.

If the detachable rake comes with a handle, I would cut that in sections to fit in your backpack, and then I would cut sections of hardwood to be bolted across the joints, pretty much the same length as your handle sections (not shorter pieces) and drill holes to bolt them together with wingnuts. If the handle is hollow, you might be able to use sections of hardwood dowel (or wooden rake handle) *inside the hollow handle,* but my base assumption is that it might be solid wood itself, so an overlapping bolted series of sticks is my thought.

Comment: I was wondering the same. Pulling a rake through the sand might be a lot of force. And then you get your friends use it and they don't take care and it breaks.

So, something like this?
[broomstick-with-wing-nuts](https://i.imgur.com/RdPuwWL.png).

Comment: Much longer overlap, which keeps the force on the joints (trying to tear them apart) lower. So if you had two handle parts, a third part, roughly the same length, bolted to both of them, overlapping each by roughly half its length. If you had 3 handle parts, 2 additional parts to overlap the joints..

Comment: This is the most robust idea I've seen mentioned. Just also wanted to add, this might be obvious but a shorter handle with fewer sections will be stronger than a longer handle with more sections.

Comment: I have a "roof rake" whose sections are aluminum tubes.  They fit together  the same way except that the insertable ends are part of the tube (reduced diameter) rather than a plastic insert.  I can guarantee you won't be able to bend/snap  them while raking :-)